# How to convert a unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) to Ruby DateTime?

Tags: ruby, datetime, timestamp

How do you convert a Unix timestamp (seconds since epoch) to Ruby DateTime?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

`DateTime.strptime` can handle seconds since epoch. The number must be converted to a string:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')
```

Comment: This doesn't handle fractional seconds

Comment: It does handle miliseconds with'`%Q` tho.

Comment: To follow up on @TheMiniJohn's answer. It looks like `Time` is necessary instead of `DateTime`.  So use `Time.strptime("1318996912345",'%Q').to_f` and you will see the milliseconds preserved, while `DateTime.strptime("1318996912345",'%Q').to_f` does not preserve it.

Comment: `Time.at 1318996912` is preferable in some cases because it infers the time for your local timezone, as WattsInABox pointed out.

Answer (score 711):

Sorry, brief moment of synapse failure. Here's the real answer.

```
require 'date'

Time.at(seconds_since_epoch_integer).to_datetime
```

**Brief example** (this takes into account the current system timezone):

```
$ date +%s
1318996912

$ irb

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Time.at(1318996912).to_datetime
 => #<DateTime: 2011-10-18T23:01:52-05:00 (13261609807/5400,-5/24,2299161)>
```

**Further update** (for UTC):

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > Time.at(1318996912).utc.to_datetime
 => #<DateTime: 2011-10-19T04:01:52+00:00 (13261609807/5400,0/1,2299161)>
```

**Recent Update**: I benchmarked the top solutions in this thread while working on a HA service a week or two ago, and was surprised to find that `Time.at(..)` outperforms `DateTime.strptime(..)` (update: added more benchmarks).

```
# ~ % ruby -v
#  => ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

irb(main):038:0> Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):039:1*   ["1318996912", "1318496912"].each do |s|
irb(main):040:2*     DateTime.strptime(s, '%s')
irb(main):041:2>   end
irb(main):042:1> end

=> #<Benchmark ... @real=2.9e-05 ... @total=0.0>

irb(main):044:0> Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):045:1>   [1318996912, 1318496912].each do |i|
irb(main):046:2>     DateTime.strptime(i.to_s, '%s')
irb(main):047:2>   end
irb(main):048:1> end

=> #<Benchmark ... @real=2.0e-05 ... @total=0.0>

irb(main):050:0* Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):051:1*   ["1318996912", "1318496912"].each do |s|
irb(main):052:2*     Time.at(s.to_i).to_datetime
irb(main):053:2>   end
irb(main):054:1> end

=> #<Benchmark ... @real=1.5e-05 ... @total=0.0>

irb(main):056:0* Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):057:1*   [1318996912, 1318496912].each do |i|
irb(main):058:2*     Time.at(i).to_datetime
irb(main):059:2>   end
irb(main):060:1> end

=> #<Benchmark ... @real=2.0e-05 ... @total=0.0>
```

Comment: Thank you... The following answer is a little more succinct, I found Time.at but was trying to find a DateTime equivalent.

Comment: It's funny but Time.at().to_datetime seems more pleasant than DateTime.strptime() simply because of readability...At least to me anyway

Comment: This is not the same as the above anser, Time.at assumes current timezone, where DateTime.strptime uses UTC.

Comment: It's not too surprising that `Time.at` outperforms `DateTime.strptime`. The latter has to parse a string, which is generally much slower than taking in a number directly.

Comment: Your benchmark isn't exactly testing `DateTime.strptime` because it's creating two new Strings every iteration which is very expensive. It's not just the string parsing like @claw said

Comment: @Claw et al - Thanks, noted. See updated benchmarks.

Comment: @WattsInABox, I missed your comment somehow, but the mere fact that strptime requires a string makes it inherently more expensive. Cheers.

Comment: @AdamEberlin I know I'm 3 years late in replying (lol) but my point was if you just create that '%s' outside of that loop, then you'll likely drastically speed up the DateTime.strptime call. You'll create 1 string instead of thousands... And also turn those ints into strings in the array itself...

Answer (score 89):

**Time Zone Handling**

I just want to clarify, even though this has been commented so future people don't miss this very important distinction.

```
DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s') # => Wed, 19 Oct 2011 04:01:52 +0000
```

displays a return value in UTC and requires the seconds to be a String and outputs a UTC Time object, whereas

```
Time.at(1318996912) # => 2011-10-19 00:01:52 -0400
```

displays a return value in the LOCAL time zone, normally requires a FixNum argument, but the Time object itself is still in UTC even though the display is not.

So even though I passed the same integer to both methods, I seemingly two different results because of how the class' `#to_s` method works. However, as @Eero had to remind me twice of:

```
Time.at(1318996912) == DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s') # => true
```

An equality comparison between the two return values still returns true. Again, this is because the values are basically the same (although different classes, the `#==` method takes care of this for you), but the `#to_s` method prints drastically different strings. Although, if we look at the strings, we can see they are indeed the same time, just printed in different time zones.

**Method Argument Clarification**

The docs also say "If a numeric argument is given, the result is in local time." which makes sense, but was a little confusing to me because they don't give any examples of non-integer arguments in the docs. So, for some non-integer argument examples:

```
Time.at("1318996912")
TypeError: can't convert String into an exact number
```

you can't use a String argument, but you can use a Time argument into `Time.at` and it will return the result in the time zone of the argument:

```
Time.at(Time.new(2007,11,1,15,25,0, "+09:00"))
=> 2007-11-01 15:25:00 +0900
```

**Benchmarks**

After a discussion with @AdamEberlin on his answer, I decided to publish slightly changed benchmarks to make everything as equal as possible. Also, I never want to have to build these again so this is as good a place as any to save them.

Time.at(int).to_datetime ~ 2.8x faster

```
09:10:58-watsw018:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
09:11:00-watsw018:~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'benchmark'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):003:0>
irb(main):004:0* format = '%s'
=> "%s"
irb(main):005:0> times = ['1318996912', '1318496913']
=> ["1318996912", "1318496913"]
irb(main):006:0> int_times = times.map(&:to_i)
=> [1318996912, 1318496913]
irb(main):007:0>
irb(main):008:0* datetime_from_strptime = DateTime.strptime(times.first, format)
=> #<DateTime: 2011-10-19T04:01:52+00:00 ((2455854j,14512s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):009:0> datetime_from_time = Time.at(int_times.first).to_datetime
=> #<DateTime: 2011-10-19T00:01:52-04:00 ((2455854j,14512s,0n),-14400s,2299161j)>
irb(main):010:0>
irb(main):011:0* datetime_from_strptime === datetime_from_time
=> true
irb(main):012:0>
irb(main):013:0* Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):014:1*   100_000.times {
irb(main):015:2*     times.each do |i|
irb(main):016:3*       DateTime.strptime(i, format)
irb(main):017:3>     end
irb(main):018:2>   }
irb(main):019:1> end
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fbdc18f0d28 @label="", @real=0.8680500000045868, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.009999999999999998, @utime=0.86, @total=0.87>
irb(main):020:0>
irb(main):021:0* Benchmark.measure do
irb(main):022:1*   100_000.times {
irb(main):023:2*     int_times.each do |i|
irb(main):024:3*       Time.at(i).to_datetime
irb(main):025:3>     end
irb(main):026:2>   }
irb(main):027:1> end
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x00007fbdc3108be0 @label="", @real=0.33059399999910966, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.32000000000000006, @total=0.32000000000000006>
```

****edited to not be completely and totally incorrect in every way****

****added benchmarks****

Comment: Seemed plausible, and I upvoted already (cannot rescind now), but upon further checking your claim regarding UTC is untrue.  The resulting DateTime/Time object will be in UTC vs local, yes, but the original timestamp is interpreted as being in UTC in both cases!  So the moment in time is equal regardless of method.  Try `Time.at(1318996912) == DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s')` in a non-UTC timezone and you will see!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you corrected is still wrong! :-)

Run `Time.use_zone "Samoa" do Time.at(1318996912) == DateTime.strptime("1318996912",'%s') end` to verify that the times are equal, there is no LOCAL timestamp, and in both cases the Unix timestamp is interpreted as being in UTC.  

`Time.at` *presents* the resulting Time object in the local time zone, and `DateTime.strptime` *presents* the resulting DateTime object in UTC, but regardless of presentation they are equal, as they are the equivalent moment in time.

Comment: The statement *whereas
`Time.at(1318996912) # => 2011-10-19 00:01:52 -0400` displays a return value in the LOCAL time zone*

does not appear to be accurate... Can you please verify? I believe your statement would only be true if you used `Time.zone.at(1318996912)`

Comment: Yeah, that appears to be accurate. My local machine is set to EST and the times display in EST.

Comment: Can you provide an example where this is not the case @BigRon? What time zone, ruby version, etc does not behave this way?

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0: `Time.zone.name #=> "Central Time (US & Canada)"` `Time.at(1318996912) #=>  2011-10-19 04:01:52 +0000` `Time.zone.at(1318996912) #=> Tue, 18 Oct 2011 23:01:52 CDT -05:00`. **Time.at** will always return time in UTC, no?

Comment: ... but the [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-c-at) appear to agree with you, "If a numeric argument is given, the result is in local time." Somehow my results are different...

Comment: Time is an mfer. I suppose I'm getting these results because of the way [Rails supers `Time.at`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08e05d4a49c1ba1327e3e6821eba1f0c93361ab2/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L42), and my Time.zone must not be set properly in Ruby

Comment: yeah, try booting into an irb console outside of any project or gemset with rails installed to verify if you're super curious

Answer (score 12):

One command to convert date time to Unix format and then to string

```
    DateTime.strptime(Time.now.utc.to_i.to_s,'%s').strftime("%d %m %y")

    Time.now.utc.to_i #Converts time from Unix format
    DateTime.strptime(Time.now.utc.to_i.to_s,'%s') #Converts date and time from unix format to DateTime
```

finally strftime is used to format date

Example:

```
    irb(main):034:0> DateTime.strptime("1410321600",'%s').strftime("%d %m %y")
    "10 09 14"
```

Comment: One thing to note is that epoch format does not have a timezone so chaining utc before chaining to_i is not necessary in `Time.now.utc.to_i`.

Answer (score 1):

This tells you the date of the number of seconds in future from the moment you execute the code.

```
time = Time.new + 1000000000 #date in 1 billion seconds
```

puts(time)

according to the current time I am answering the question it prints `047-05-14 05:16:16 +0000` (1 billion seconds in future)

or if you want to count billion seconds from a particular time, it's in format `Time.mktime(year, month,date,hours,minutes)`

```
time = Time.mktime(1987,8,18,6,45) + 1000000000
```

puts("I would be 1 Billion seconds old on: "+time)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted just a Date, you can do `Date.strptime(invoice.date.to_s, '%s')` where `invoice.date` comes in the form of an`Fixnum` and then converted to a `String`.

Comment: `Time.at(1500923406).to_date.to_s` => `"2017-07-24"`