# Date Time parsing in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I need to parse a file, first column contains this as I suggest it is timestamp. But I do not know encoding, so I decided to ask here maybe it's common encoding.

I have timestamps:

1. 201003568295
2. 960000188940

How can I get Date and Time or only Date from this?

Comment: I think no, it is different format, not unix

Comment: Where did these numbers come from? Do you know what dates and times the correspond to at least?

Comment: I need to parse a file, first column contains this as I suggest it is timestamp. But I do not know encoding, so I decided to ask here maybe it's common encoding.

Comment: It's not useful to repeat your question in the comments. Instead, explain your needs and why you think it is a date, in your question by editing it and add that information in at the appropriate places. The value is not a standard time in seconds as it's an extremely large range, and it doesn't make sense that the two would be related times. We need more context. What TYPE of file is it, what does it contain or what is its source?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816365/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-seconds-since-epoch-to-ruby-datetime).

```
require 'date'
new_date = Time.at(960000188940).to_datetime
 #=> Wed, 13 Mar 32391 12:39:00 +053
```

Comment: That date would only seem normal to an astrophysicist.