# Convert unix hex timestamp to ruby datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hex, unix-timestamp

i have hex timestamp like this `'6132103D'` (got it from facebook API) according to [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/hex) service i get expected date `Friday, September 3, 2021 12:08:29 PM`.
I have seen [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816365/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-seconds-since-epoch-to-ruby-datetime) discussion but there is no any success

Cannot use `Time.at` because i operate with String.

Be thankful if you suggest some solution or gem which i could use.

ruby 2.7.1
rails 6.0.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert hex value to decimal.

Then, use `Time.at()` or `DateTime.strptime()` function to get the timestamp

```
2.5.3 :019 > DateTime.strptime(str.to_i(16).to_s, '%s')
 => Fri, 03 Sep 2021 12:08:29 +0000 

2.5.3 :020 > Time.at(str.to_i(16))
 => 2021-09-03 17:38:29 +0530
```

Crossverified using https://www.epochconverter.com/hex

```
hex timestamp : 6132103D
```

Equivalent timestamp:

```
GMT: Friday, September 3, 2021 12:08:29 PM
Your time zone: Friday, September 3, 2021 5:38:29 PM GMT+05:30
Decimal timestamp/epoch: 1630670909
```

Comment: Even simpler: `Time.at(str.hex)`